I'm trying to use Xcode Instruments 15.3 to analyze the http traffic of my application, but the instruments do not collect the data of simulator
I'm trying to use Instruments to monitor the app's HTTP traffic, but the profile is not collecting any data.
I'm trying to follow this article step by step to collect the data I need:
https://www.kodeco.com/27390649-monitoring-http-traffic-with-instruments
However, when I try to select Netowork Connection I receive the following error message and the instrument does not even allow me to save the profile:

"Recording of 'Network Connections' is not supported in the Simulator."
"Remove the Network Connections instrument and try again."
And when I remove Netowork Connection, despite being able to record, instruments don't record anything

The code I made to make the request is a simple code using SwiftUI and URLSession

I'm using Xcode and Instruments 15.3 and the iPhone 15 simulator with iOS 17.4, I tried with other simulators with iOS 16, and also without success.

Unfortunately, recording HTTP traffic using the Instruments tool is not supported for the simulator, despite it not showing an error.
You will need to use a physical device, in which case you should see data showing up.
You will see this confirmed by various websites, including my own experience.
As an alternative, I recommend Charles or Proxyman

WireShark is another option.
